# Why would S3 bucket connection require EC2 access when connecting from a remote app

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, remote-access, firewall

I have an .NET app that upload files to S3 bucket. The app hosted in a server in a closed network, so we created firewall rule to whitelist outbound traffic to S3(AP-Southeast-2) IP ranges. We noticed that there are intermittent connection issues and throwing following exception;

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status SendFailure was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
```

We no longer get intermittent connection issue when we allow all outbound traffic. But we noticed that there are outbound traffic to EC2 IP range as well.

Question: Why would S3 bucket connection require EC2 access when connecting from a remote app?

Comment: An IP might be registered for both S3 and EC2.  For instance, right now, `3.5.0.0/19` is registered as both EC2 and S3 according to ip-ranges.json.  There are something like 75,000 IP addresses like this, it changes from time to time.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward. I noticed 2 IP ranges listed in both S3 and EC2 IP ranges for AP-Southeast-2. This still doesn't explain why I see other EC2 IP ranges in the FW traffic.